# Determinant of matrix where the $i$-th column is $A$ times the $i-1$-th column for some matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Given a vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, I was wondering whether there was a simple expression for the determinant of the matrix $B$ defined by
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix} & | & & | & & | && | \\ x & | & Ax +v& | & A^2x+ Av & | & \cdots & | & A^{n-1}x+A^{n-2}v \\ & | & & | & & | && | \end{pmatrix}.
$$
This matrix arises when studying ODE systems of the kind $x'(t)=Ax(t)+v$, and one wishes to study the independence of the components of $x$.

Comment: Applying the transformation to your second column doesn't give the third, it gives $A^2 x + A v + v$.

Comment: Yes, I quickly realized it and corrected it.